# Multiplexing non-blocking socket IOs with EOF

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking, multiplexing

I am implementing a non-blocking socket IO reactor using linux `select`. Let's say, a server and a client are in communication. If the client or the server is down, the other side is supposed to receive an `EOF` which can be told by the return value of `read` call (C function call).

```
if(read(fd, ...) == 0) { printf("Endpoint connection failed\n"); }
```

My question is, will this `EOF` event be overlapped or merged with other data read? For example, the client sends `1 byte` to the server and accidentally shutdowns immediately. If they happen very close by time, is the `read` on server still separable to `1 byte` and `EOF`?

Comment: If you know your using Linux, I would recommend that you avoid `select` and use `epoll` instead. Or consider an evented library such as `libev`... I'm writing [my own framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools) since I love to tinker with these things. You can have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other end sends one byte and then closes the connection, then you will first read one byte, and then the *next* call to `read` will return 0.

There's no way for a single `read` call to do both - because it has to return 0 to indicate closure, and non-0 if it read some data.

Answer (score 0):

The EOS will be delivered after any pending data.